# How to implement an index like action, that limits the fields displayed depending on user parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I want to implement an action that functions just like `index`, but with the catch being that if the in the request URL, it specifies that it wants field 1 and field 2, it should only render field 1 and field 2.

Now this would be trivial if it's only done for a JSON response, but how do I implement this for HTML views too ?

The only way I can think of is having a separate view for each combination of fields, but that would be insane. Surely there must be a way that I am completely oblivious of to implement this.

Comment: Have you tried? You have to assign something for your views to render (Rails tends to use instance variables for this). You control how the controller passes data to the view, and you control the view. If you've got anything at all working right now (unfiltered), this is trivial.

Comment: @JimStewart What i tried to do naively, is just to select certain fields in the index action but this causes a crash when it tries to render the index view because it still expects the other fields to be present, the problem is i've only ever worked with backend services and JSON apis, i'm completely clueless when it comes to views, i have checked some small tutorials, but nothing that really helped me in this specific problem. And to answer your questions, yes i've already have stuff working, only because i used a scaffold though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating an instance variable called fields, and i figured out a neat enough way to write the index view code for it not to be too cluttery

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Articles</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <% @fields = ["headline", "content", "locale", "classification" ]  unless @fields.present? %>
    <tr>
      <% @fields.each do |field| %>
        <th><%= "#{field.titleize}" %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
      <tr>
        <% @fields.each do |field| %>
        <td><%= simple_format article.send(field) %></td>
        <% end %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', article %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Article', new_article_path %>
```